# How do I change the background of a Frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, background, tkinter, frame

I have been creating an *Email* program using Tkinter, in Python 3.3.
On various sites I have been seeing that the Frame widget can get a different background using `Frame.config(background="color")`.
However, when I use this in my Frames it gives the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Background"
```

It does not work when doing the following:

```
frame = Frame(root, background="white")
```

Or:

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.config(bg="white")
```

I can't figure it out.
I would post my whole source code but I dont want it exposed on the internet, but the frame creation goes something like this:

```
mail1 = Frame(self, relief=SUNKEN)
mail1.pack()
mail1.place(height=70, width=400, x=803, y=109)
mail1.config(Background="white")
```

I have tried multiple options trying to modify the background. The frame is like a wrap around an email preview for an inbox.

In case it's needed, this the way I am importing my modules:

```
import tkinter, time, base64, imaplib, smtplib
from imaplib import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

The following is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Wessel\Dropbox\Python\Main\Class Ginomail.py", line 457, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Wessel\Dropbox\Python\Main\Class Ginomail.py", line 453, in main
app = Application(root) #start the application with root as the parent
File "C:\Users\Wessel\Dropbox\Python\Main\Class Ginomail.py", line 60, in __init__
self.initINBOX()
File "C:\Users\Wessel\Dropbox\Python\Main\Class Ginomail.py", line 317, in initINBOX
mail1.config(bg="white")
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1263, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

Gives the following error with the code from the answer:

```
  File "C:\Users\Wessel\Dropbox\Python\Main\Class Ginomail.py", line 317, in initINBOX
  mail1 = Frame(self, relief=SUNKEN, style='myframe')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 733, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 553, in __init__
  tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2075, in __init__
  (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
  _tkinter.TclError: Layout myframe not found
```

---

Solved! Thanks. Its the inbox bar to the right, background needed to be white.
[image: Happy with the results, lets work on that inbox scrolling.]

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix `place`, `pack` and `grid` methods.

Comment: Okay thanks, I used it since someone used it in a Tkinter tutorial, and it stuck since. I will optimise my code to only use place.

Comment: It's better to use `place` or `grid` on 99% cases.

Comment: @kalgasnik Yep, I found that when using 'code'pack'code' I could not create the interface i wanted.

Comment: `Layout myframe not found`: `myframe` is not correct name for style

Comment: @kalgasnik Thought I could use myframe as the name. Works now, thanks! Another question, the labels that go in the frame have a grey background so it still doesnt show the white BG. is there anyway to make the label background transparant?

Comment: @kalgasnik: I think you are giving some bad advice. `place` is rarely the right choice; both `pack` and `grid` generally give better results than `place`. Also, it's ok to mix them in an app, you just can't mix them in the same container widget.

Comment: @kalgasnik I tried using both Pack and Grid, and I didnt like pack at all and grid was just messing up my layout and I had to make so many changes. Though I know Place is bad because of different screen resolutions. It works perfectly for my resolution though. I may change it to grid later.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, It's `Ctrl-V` mistake, thanks for note.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are unknowingly using the `Frame` class from the `ttk` package rather than from the `tkinter` package. The one from `ttk` does not support the background option.

This is the main reason why you shouldn't do wildcard imports -- you can overwrite the definition of classes and commands.

I recommend doing imports like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttk
```

Then you prefix the widgets with either `tk` or `ttk` :

```
f1 = tk.Frame(..., bg=..., fg=...)
f2 = ttk.Frame(..., style=...)
```

It then becomes instantly obvious which widget you are using, at the expense of just a tiny bit more typing. If you had done this, this error in your code would never have happened.

Comment: Thanks! Will use it in the future. Normally I use `import tkinter as tk` but I left it tkinter because I was converting my program from loose functions to a class based program.

Comment: @N.McA.: it _is_ a source of bugs if you do global imports, which is why I give this advice. With good programming habits it becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Fantastic answer, and great catch.

Answer (score 18):

You use `ttk.Frame`, `bg` option does not work for it.  [You should create style and apply it to the frame.](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 

root = Tk()

s = Style()
s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')

mail1 = Frame(root, style='My.TFrame')
mail1.place(height=70, width=400, x=83, y=109)
mail1.config()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep, my window is 1000 wide.

Comment: Still get the "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg" " error somehow, still after removing the .pack() from all my frames.

Comment: not sure how the formatting of the comment section works, ill post in OP

Comment: @kalgasnik: in a comment you wrote "Code with 'bg' works fine (python2.7 and 3.3)." That is true, but you're missing the point of this answer. It works when you use the standard `Frame` from tkinter, but the OP was (accidentally?) using the one from the `ttk` package where it won't work.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm pretty new to programming, so I guess it was an accident yes. It works now though. Also from what I understand if you use `Style` you can't use things like `bg="white"` anymore, right? Because I tried it on some labels and they gave the same error.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I edited my answer after IPDGino added imports.

Comment: This sample code didn't give me red background but rather grey with py2.7.12 on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This solution does not work for me on macOS Mojave with Python 3.7.4.

Comment: it's old - but: I gave this answer a "downvote" because of the two `import` staments: using it this way how will you control which e.g. Frame you will use: tk.Frame or ttk.Frame - it's a bit mor writing but with `import tkinter ask` and `import tkinter.ttk as tkk` would be much clearer (and more controllable)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most experienced at tkinter. But..

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()

mail1 = app.Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN, background="white", height=70, width=400)
mail1.pack()
mail1.place(x=803, y=109)

app.mainloop()
```

Is working for me, make sure you have the latest python and tkinter