# Python Tkinter: TypeError: 'Frame' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I created a gui program with frames to move from page to page and I got it working while using methods only, but as soon as I introduce a class I get the following Error:

`TypeError: 'Frame' object is not callable`

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class teachingContent(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(teachingContent, self).__init__()

        self.first_title_frame = ttk.Frame()
        self.first_frame = ttk.Frame()

    def nextButtonPressed(self):
        pass

    def prevButtonPressed(self):
        pass

    def formSize(self):
        self.geometry("650x450+200+200") # Sets the size of the gui
        self.title("Python Tutor")

        self.nbutton = Button(text = "Next", command = self.nextButtonPressed).place(x=561,y=418)

        self.pbutton = Button(text = "Previous", command = self.prevButtonPressed).place(x=0,y=418)

        title_height = 40

        self.first_title_frame(self, height=title_height, bg = 'black')
        self.first_title_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        self.first_title_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=35, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))


        self.first_frame(self, bg = 'DarkSlateGray4')
        self.first_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        self.first_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
        self.first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=33, pady=50, sticky=(W, N, E))

        self.label = Label(self.first_title_frame, text = "Welcome to the Tutor").pack()

        self.label = Label(self.first_frame, text = "Welcome to the Python Tutor. In this program you will learn to tools and techniques need to use Python.")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=85,pady=11, padx=11, sticky=(N))

tc = teachingContent()
tc.formSize()
```

I made a change to the code in this line adding `.configure` as follows:

`self.first_title_frame.configure(self, height=title_height, bg = 'black')`

but this gives me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tete De Bite\Dropbox\Year3\FinalYearProject\pythonTutoringSystem\debug.py", line 47, in <module>
   tc.formSize()
  File "C:\Users\Tete De Bite\Dropbox\Year3\FinalYearProject\pythonTutoringSystem\debug.py", line 31, in formSize
    self.first_title_frame.configure(self, height=title_height, bg = 'black')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1263, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-pady"
```

Does anyone have any ideas that will correct the programming mistake I am making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.first_title_frame.configure(self, height=title_height, bg = 'black')
```

You don't need to pass `self` as a parameter here.

```
self.first_title_frame.configure(height=title_height, bg = 'black')
```

In any case, `ttk.Frame`s don't seem to allow you to directly configure their background colors. `bg` is not listed [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_frame.htm) under "standard options" or "widget-specific options". Try using the `style` argument instead, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639454/953482) post.

Comment: ok I tried removing self but I still get exactly the same error.

Comment: Does it still say `unknown option "-pady"`, or something else?

Comment: It says `unknown option "-bg"`

Comment: Right, because `bg` isn't a valid attribute for ttk frames. I've edited my post to discuss that.