# IndexError out of range when changing styles

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, indexoutofrangeexception

So far in a program I have been writing, I have used basic tkinter for widgets. However, after some Googling, I found out about `ttk` and its themed widgets.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style) on the Python Docs site, I only needed to add `from tkinter.ttk import *` to make use of the ttk widgets without needing to change any code, so it seemed worth it to me.

Of course, the only thing that wouldn't work is the `-bg` flag. However, when I try and use the `ttk` styling, I get:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

of all things, though I wrote nothing in code referred to a *range*.

This is the particular section of code:

```
style = Style()
# stuff
style.map("rbstyle", background="grey")
# stuff
crBox = Label(win, width=6, textvariable=cr, 
              state='normal', relief='sunk', style="rbstyle")
```

and this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Google Drive\Queens' Athletics\window.py", line 83, in <module>
    style.map("rbstyle", background="grey")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 402, in map
    self.tk.call(self._name, "map", style, *(_format_mapdict(kw))))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 111, in _format_mapdict
    _format_optvalue(_mapdict_values(value), script)))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 85, in _mapdict_values
    state[0] # raise IndexError if empty
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Why am I having this error? I followed exactly what it said on Python Docs.

Comment: Your attempt looks very little like the examples shown, where it says (emphasis mine) *"Each key in kw is an option and each value **should be a list or a tuple** (usually) containing statespecs grouped in tuples, lists, or some other preference. A statespec is a compound of one or more states and then a value."* Have you mixed up `map` and `configure`?

Comment: Hm, checking it again I see what you mean. I just tried `configure` instead, but that gives me an error too: `_tkinter.TclError: Layout rbstyle not found`. Should I be defining the layout differently?

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16639125/3001761?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it to work after checking that post. Something that somebody said (Layout myframe not found: myframe is not correct name for style - @kalgasnik) made me wonder, so I changed my layout name to `TLabel` as that kind of format seemed to be used in **ALL** of the examples. After doing this it just _worked_. Any chance you could explain this behaviour? Put that as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!