# Having trouble changing background color in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm practicing coding in Python. Here is what I am testing and messing around with.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class gui_programming(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        frame =
        frame.config(bg="red")

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(selfself, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = gui_programming()
app.geometry("400x200+10+10")
app.mainloop()
```

However I am curious and stumped as to what frame should be set to so that I can change the background color to something other than default.

Comment: Seems like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639125/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-frame-in-tkinter`

Comment: @ccf: nope, definitely not a duplicate of that.

Comment: reading that answer, now I feel stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame` shouldn't set to anything. The object itself is a frame:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg="red")
```