# How to change the background color of a TKinter Column?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have the a Tkinter App, but I'd like to change the background color to Blue of the first column

[image: Tkinter Application]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 500 200")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="COLUMN 1 ROW 1").grid(column=1, row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried the following, but I receive an error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 500 200")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="COLUMN 1 ROW 1").grid(column=1, row=1,bg ="blue4")
root.mainloop()
```

tkinter.TclError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chriscruz/Desktop/aesop_1.1.py", line 11, in <module>
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="COLUMN 1 ROW 1").grid(column=1, row=1,bg ="blue4")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2029, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bg": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Answer (score 3):

`ttk.Label` doesn't have the option `bg` instead it has `style` option which you can configure like the following:

```
lbl = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="COLUMN 1 ROW 1")
style_ref = ttk.Style()
style_ref.configure("style_name.TLabel", background='blue')
lbl['style'] = "style_name.TLabel"
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

or if you were to use `tkinter.Label` instead:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(mainframe, text="COLUMN 1 ROW 1")
lbl['bg'] = 'blue'
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Frame` class from the `ttk` package doesn't support the background option so try using just tkinter itself.

See a similar question here: [How do I change the background of a Frame in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639125/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-frame-in-tkinter)