# How do i change the background color of a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the background of the window of my gui. Can someone explain why this don't work.

I am using python version 3.6.3

```
    from tkinter import *


class Window(Frame):

    #Initialize the Window
    def __init__(self, master=None, bg = "#a6a6a6"):

        # Parameters that you want to send through the window
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.bg = bg


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16639125/7032856

Comment: your title asks about changing the color of a _frame_, but the first sentence asks about setting the color of the _window_. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.master.configure(background='black')
```

Should do the job.

You make a variable called `self.bg` which stores the background color, however dont set it. Replace `self.bg` with the above code and change black to reflect the desired color.

e.g. `self.master.configure(background=bg)`

The resulting code would be

```
from tkinter import *
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, bg = "#a6a6a6"):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(background='black')

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```