# Black Frame doesn't display | tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to add a frame in my Tkinter application but nothing works

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()

screen_width=app.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height=app.winfo_screenheight()
print(screen_height, screen_width)
app.geometry("%dx%d" % (screen_width,screen_height))



frame=Frame(app, bg='black')
frame.pack()


    

app.mainloop()
```

this was the code. the black frame doesn't display with this code. I don't know why.. I am a beginner here

Comment: Post a screenshot of the output

Comment: There is no widget in the frame, so its size is 1x1 by default. Try setting the width and height of the frame to some values.

Answer (score -1):

I played around a bit and with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084555/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-frame-in-tkinter) i figured out that you need to utilize `Frame.master.configure(background="black")`. I modified your example and used `random` to select a background color from a list of strings if you click a button. Hope that helps you to get started. Also, i advise you not to use star imports, rather import each widget you use independently (e.g. `from tkinter import Frame, Label, Tk, Button` and so on..)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def change_background_color():
    """Test-function to switch background color of Window object"""
    colors = ["black", "blue", "red", "yellow", "orange", "gray", "green"]
    app.master.configure(background=random.choice(colors))

# create root object, set window size based on screen size
root=Tk()
root.geometry(f"{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{root.winfo_screenheight()}")

# create child-frame with background color
app = Frame(root)
app.master.configure(background="black")

# create test-widgets
test_label = Label(root, text="Hello", bg="gray", fg="yellow").pack()
test_button = Button(root, text="Click me", bg="blue", fg="red", command=change_background_color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you .
I was actually planning to create more than 1 frame in a window. but I can't reduce the size of the frame which you created..

but I found a solution that create a canvas and set a frame in there..

canva = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400, bg="black")
canva.pack()

fram = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
fram.place(relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8, relx=0.1,rely=0.1)